# Visual C++ 2010 project properties macros - how to edit?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros

I need to change the value of macro TargetExt. How can I do this? I can't find a way to do that from IDE (??!) and those macros aren't stored in project file either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: Project -> NAME properties... -> Configuration properties -> Target Extension